# PHP KITE API V3: Code Exit after placing an order

Tags: php, kite

Using the PHP KITE API V3.0; order can be placed successfully.

```php
 $order_id = $kite->placeOrder("regular", [
    "tradingsymbol" => "SBIN",
    "exchange" => "NSE",
    "quantity" => "1",
    "transaction_type" => "BUY",
    "order_type" => "MARKET",
    "product" => "MIS"
])["order_id"];
```

But after this script;  code is automatically exit even a single print is not working.
Because of exiting the code; I can not place save the details of order placing at our DB; also can not place second order.

Please guide how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? (In the central PHP configuration, not from within the script itself.) If not, go and do that first of all.

Comment: @misorude Yes, I have used ini_set("display_errors", 1) to show the error. But, nothing is shown after place order function.